# Find all paths in a graph

Tags: python, performance, recursion, graph, memoization

My code does a DFS on the given graph and prints all possible paths for a given start and end node. My question is how can this be improved?

1. Can some form of memoization be used here? There are cases where a path from a certain source - destination is already found and will be an intermediate path for a different source - destination but it is still computed again.
2. As it is a generator will that make memoization different?
3. Is there an already existing text book algorithm that I am missing? Does not have to be specifically DFS.
4. Pythonic / Idiomatic code suggestions are also welcome.

This is my code

```
from itertools import product

def find_path(g, src, dst):
    """Prints all possible path for a graph `g` for all pairs in `src` and `dst`
    
    Args:
        g (list): 2d list, graph
        src (list): list of nodes that will be the source
        dst (list): list of nodes that will be the destination
    """

    graph = {}

    # constructing a graph
    for from_, to_ in g:
        graph.setdefault(from_, set()).add(to_)
        graph.setdefault(to_, set()).add(from_) # undirected

    def dfs(src, dst, path, seen):
        """Recursive generator that yields all paths from `src` to `dst`
        
        Args:
            src (int): source node
            dst (int): destination node
            path (list): path so far
            seen (set): set of visited nodes
        
        Yields:
            list: all paths from `src` to `dst`
        """
        if src in seen:
            return

        if src == dst:
            yield path + [src]
            return

        seen.add(src)

        for i in graph.get(src, []):
            yield from dfs(i, dst, path + [src], seen)
        seen.remove(src)


    # start finding path for all `src` `dst` pairs
    for source, destination in product(src, dst):
        print(source, destination, list(dfs(source, destination, [], set())))


g = list(product(range(1, 5), repeat=2)) # a graph for testing purpose
src = dst = range(1, 5) # source and destination, in actual code this will be a list
find_path(g, src, dst)
```

Comment: Is there any additional details needed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I don't think memoization will be useful here. Any correct algorithm is going to be *O(n!)*, nothing you do can reduce that fundamentally because you still have to *output* all the paths.
   Trying to cache stuff you already output is just going to make the space-costs worse, it won't make the processing-time any better.
2. The advantages of using a generator are that the caller doesn't have to wait for the whole computation to finish before handling the early outputs, and that we never have to *store* the results of the whole computation at once. This is a good choice for the task at hand!
   It doesn't affect the point in (1.) though.
3. [You seem to have already found the textbook algorithm.](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/simple-paths-between-two-vertices)
4. There are various things to make the code prettier, but you'd have to do some testing to see if they make it work better.

   - Types are nice. They do nothing at runtime, but they let [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) check for many kinds of mistakes.
   - I don't like the redundancy of `path` and `seen`, and I don't like that you're mutating `seen` the way you are, but I suspect the way you've written it is actually the most efficient for larger graphs.
   - The expression `path + [src]` makes two calls to the `list` constructor, and it's happening inside the `for` loop. That can be improved!
   - Since you never mutate a value of `path`, it can be a tuple instead of a list.
   - The way you have it set up now, your adjacencies dict will always contain `src`, so you don't need to use `get`.

I'm ignoring your outer wrapper, and I've made no effort to test this:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Mapping, MutableSet, Sequence, TypeVar
N = TypeVar('N')
def dfs(source: N,  # The current node
        destination: N,  # The destination node
        path: Sequence[N],  # The path taken to the current node
        seen: MutableSet[N],  # The nodes visited on the path
        graph: Mapping[N, Iterable[N]]  # The graph being explored, as an adjacency dict
) -> Iterable[Sequence[N]]:
    new_path = (*path, source)
    if source == destination:
        yield new_path
    else:
        seen.add(source)
        for n in graph[source]:
            if n not in seen:
                yield from dfs(n, destination, new_path, seen, graph)
        seen.remove(source)
```

Comment: thank you for answering this, *"don't like that you're mutating seen the way you are"*, can you suggest any other ways this can be done?

Comment: The other options would be to make a new set for the recursive `seen`, like you you're doing with `path`. Mutating values is often efficient, but opens up its own class of bugs. But as I understand it's somewhat expensive to spin up a new `set` instance (relative to other basic structures), so for this purpose your way is probably better.

Comment: I have one other question, assume a path exists like so `'1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6'` and before that computation, I have already computed `'2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5'`, that was what I meant when I said how memoization can be used, as you can see, the second path is part of the result of the first path, can I not take advantage of this? I will clarify if you need more details

Comment: also, I will give the bounty to you if I dont get any other even more well written answer, just want to clarify things before :)

Comment: I understand what you mean by memoization, and I don't think it's going to help here. Suppose you've cached (memoized) the `2...5` path. Probably you've also cached all the other paths from 2. Great, but three problems: 1) You still have to iterate over all those `2...` paths and output them; I don't think you can do that _fundamentally_ faster than just rebuilding them all as-needed. 2) You have to store them all somewhere; that could be costly and/or slow. 3) You can't just iterate over _all_ of them; any containing a `1` must be excluded, so there's still extra computation to do.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you

Comment: thank you @ShapeOfMatter